# Look at the sortList(...) function in the given code. After sorting the element and pushing it into another LL its order is getting jacked up. WHY?

Tags: python, sorting, linked-list

Problem Statement: Given a linked list L of N nodes. Sort the linked list.
Example:
Input: 1 -> -2 -> -3 -> 4 -> -5
Output: -5 -> -3 -> -2 -> 1 -> 4

But when i run the code i get output :
For Input:
1 -2 -3 4 -5
your output is:
1 -2 -3 4 -5

But i think my code is logically correct. What am i missing here.
Also i can only make edits to the sortList function as rest of all the codes is Boilerplate code.

```
def sortList(head):
    temp=head
    arr=[]
    while temp!=None:
        arr.append(temp.data)
        temp=temp.next
    arr.sort()
    ll1=LinkedList()
    for i in arr:
        ll1.append(i)
    return ll1.head

#Initial Template for Python 3
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):   # data -> value stored in node
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, new_value):
        new_node = Node(new_value)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return
        curr_node = self.head
        while curr_node.next is not None:
            curr_node = curr_node.next
        curr_node.next = new_node
        

    
def PrintList(head):
    while head:
        print(head.data,end=' ')
        head=head.next


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t=int(input())
    for cases in range(t):
        
        n=int(input())
        ll = LinkedList() # create a new linked list 'll'.
        nodes_ll = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
        for nodes in nodes_ll:
            ll.append(nodes)  # add to the end of the list
        
        sortList(ll.head)
        PrintList(ll.head)
        print()
```

Comment: ```5 -> -3 -> -2 -> 1 -> 4``` cannot understand that

Comment: In the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block, `sortList` is being invoked in such a way that it isn't doing anything with the return value. This is an indication that you are expected to modify the original linked list in-place, which is not what you're doing. You are making `sortList` return a new linked list.

Comment: `ll2_ = sortList(ll.head)
        PrintList(ll2_)` store the sorted ll

Comment: NB: such code challenges are intended for you to do the job without converting the linked list to a native list,... even more: to do it with just O(1) auxiliary memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your approach to work, you will only need to change the return line of your method to `ll.head = ll1.head`.

However, you shold not convert the linked list into a python list. Here ill give you a code that will sort the linked list using an O(n^2) method, taking the minimun value each time, swapping and finally calling recursive in the rest of the list, if you need more speed you can try quick sort.

```
def sortList(head):

    if not head.next:
        return head

    min = head
    ite = head
    while ite.next:
        ite = ite.next
        if ite.data < min.data:
            min = ite
    head.data, min.data = min.data, head.data
    sortList(head.next)
```